# Rails 3 Routing Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on making an image server that is similar to that of Flickr's. In my routes file I have:

```
get "/image/server/:secret_:id(_:size).:format", :to => "api/images#server", :as => :api_image
```

And then in my view I'm calling the following but keep getting a ActionController::RoutingError exception:

```
api_image_path({ :secret=>"07fde2a9c76de3d16fb70e772d944652", :id=>2, :size=>"t", :format=>"png" })
```

Error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"api/images", :action=>"server", :secret=>"07fde2a9c76de3d16fb70e772d944652", :id=>2, :size=>"t", :format=>"png"}
```

**Update**

The Request parameters look like the following. It seems like it's not detecting the underscore between the secret and id. It's merging it all into secret. For example if I request: http://example.com/image/server/07fde2a9c76de3d16fb70e772d944652_2_n.jpg I'll get the following in my params:

```
{"secret_"=>"07fde2a9c76de3d16fb70e772d944652_2_",
 "id"=>"n",
 "format"=>"jpg"}
```

It's taking the whole string right up to before the _n and assigning that to secret, which for some reason it's calling it secret_.

**ActionController::RoutingError (Full Trace)**

```
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:424:in `raise_routing_error'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:397:in `generate'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:453:in `generate'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:481:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:131:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb:99:in `url_for'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:195:in `api_image_url'
app/views/services/about.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_services_about_html_erb__1824827504506770107_2158066880_1802331327662141069'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `block in _render_template'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:114:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:108:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:101:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:92:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
thinking-sphinx (2.0.3) lib/thinking_sphinx/action_controller.rb:12:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `block in _run__3222905760235059467__process_action__3328463717343760166__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:220:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_188'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:330:in `around'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:314:in `_callback_around_35'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:219:in `_conditional_callback_around_188'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in `_run__3222905760235059467__process_action__3328463717343760166__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:120:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:55:in `call!'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:22:in `call'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:55:in `call!'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:22:in `call'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:55:in `call!'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:22:in `call'
oa-core (0.2.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `call'
lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:20:in `call'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.0.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
lib/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:295:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:353:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.3) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.2) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.2) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Hi @Kyle, could you please post the error log :D

Comment: Maybe api_image_path is the wrong method. run rake:routes and it will show the route names.

Comment: @eggie5 I ran it and it's showing up as api_image.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the exception as well.

Comment: why not separate secret from the filename? /secret/id/filename.jog? wouldnt the ystill need to "know" the secret to access the image?

Comment: That's what I might end up doing. I'm more just curious now about how to do it w/ the variables separated by an underscore or if it can be done at all in Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues it that the Routing Parser only supports forward slash, dot and question marker as the seperator in it's default collection, so it doesn't see the '_' as a valid separator and your are getting a match off everything except one character for :id when you match.  Additionally your parameter is secret_ because the router doesn't recognize _ as a separator and includes it in your segment name.

I think your choices are either to move from _ to forward slash (this would at least temporarily confirm if the problem is real.  Or write a custom constraint as described in section 3.8 and 3.10 of the routing guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

You can read more on the route matching here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing 
and here
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. I decided just to just use a forward slash instead.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore is a valid character for a URL parameter. I hope this would solve your problem

```
get "/image/server/:secret_:id(_:size).:format", :to => "api/images#server", :as => :api_image, :contraints => {:secret => /[\w\d]+/, :id => /[\d]+/, :size => /\w/}
```

Comment: Closer but it's still appending an underscore to the end of **secret**'s name & value. So my params still look like _"secret\_":"07fde2a9c76de3d16fb70e772d944652_"_

Comment: Hmm. I see. `\w` also takes underscore. use this `:secret => /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/`

Comment: Again, underscore is a valid letter for identifier. Thats why rails is considering `:secret_` is the name of the variable, not only `:secret`. You may use just a dash `-` instead of underscore. Well, there should be a way to separate variable from other valid characters though